# cpuid.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ouput'

Tags: assembly

```
    .section .data
output: .ascii "The processor vendor ID is 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'\n"
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
   movl $0, %eax
   cpuid
   movl $output, %edi
   movl %ebx, 28(%edi)
   movl %edx, 32(%edi)
   movl %ecx, 36(%edi)
   movl $4, %eax
   movl $1, %ebx
   movl $ouput, %ecx
   movl $42, %edx
   int $0X80
   movl $1, %eax
   movl $0, %ebx
   int $0X80
```

Why do I get that error?. Why cant it see my output variable in the data section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can* see your `output` variable in the data section. What it *cannot* see is the `ouput` variable, which you haven't defined.

The variable `ouput` is *not* the same as `output`. It would be *nice* if we had super-intelligent machines that could automatically associate the two (as our impressive built-for-pattern-matching brains can) but alas, it is not yet so.

The line should be changed from:

```
movl $ouput, %ecx
```

to:

```
movl $output, %ecx
;       ^
```

Comment: Thanks, dammit.. I am used to working in an IDE. Writing so much code in a notepad can be such a pain :(